# speech synthesis - How to change gender?

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

I've created a simple text-to-speech web app that uses window.speechSynthesis, and it's working well. I'd like to add the ability to set certain text in female, and other text in male voice.

1. It seems that if I use getVoices() from web speech API, the list varies from browser to browser.  There doesn't seem to be a property for "gender".  Some of the chrome names have 'Male' in them, some don't. Some have female names and male names.
   Google chrome doesn't seem to have a male US speaker listed. Am I missing something?
2. If I knew what all the names possibly could be, then I could store the list, and just go through the list until I find one that works.  **Is there a way to know if a voice has been enabled on that device?**
3. Or, is there a way to download (with my app) a male and a female voice that will work in all browsers?

I need this to work on all devices.

Comment: No, there is no specs defined way to know what gender is the SpeechSynthesisVoice, nor is there any list of default voices that will be available on all browsers + systems.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd create an array of the desired voice names (male and female), then iterate through the `getVoices` array to find a match. For example:

```js
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => {
  const maleVoices = [
    'Google US English Male',
    'Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)',
  ];
  const foundVoice = speechSynthesis.getVoices()
    .find(({ name }) => maleVoices.includes(name));
  console.log('speaking');
  speechSynthesis.cancel(); // sometimes needed due to Chrome's buggy implementation
  const utter = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('foo bar');
  if (foundVoice) utter.voice = foundVoice;
  else console.log('no voice found, using default');
  speechSynthesis.speak(utter);
};
```

The voices available are determined by the browser and the user's computer; there's no way to download additional voices through Javascript if the user doesn't have the desired ones.

My Google Chrome 66 does have both `'Google US English Male'` and `'Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)'`.

Comment: How to get a list of possible voice names?  Is there a list online somewhere ?

Comment: By [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Microsoft+David+Desktop+-+English+(United+States)%22+%22Google+UK+English+Female%22) I found a bunch of lists.

Comment: CertainPerformance thanks for your help!  The above code works in chrome, but not when I test on mobile safari.  All I get is the default voice.  Is there some extra step I'm missing?

Comment: Try calling `getVoices()` in mobile Safari to figure out the list of voices it has, and then insert the desirable ones' names (if any).

Comment: Yeay I did that and I get a whole list.  I put in Tom and Samantha, but I only get whatever is set on my phone as default, either Tom OR Samantha, it doesn't switch. I'm on iPhone7 version 11.3.1. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure the name matches *exactly* or it won't work. `console.log` the names and copy them directly.